# radius configuring functions in policy.conf

Tags: function, module, policy, freeradius

I'm trying to configure for freeRadius v.2.1.12 some sql statements, following the suggestions for setting up lockout statements here- https://wiki.freeradius.org/guide/lockout . I am putting a function in policy.conf with the simplest possible routine, to try to isolate loading problems:

```
lockout_test {
  update control {
    Tmp-Integer-0 := "%{sql:select 1}"
  }
}
```

This fails when I add lockout_test to reload the radiusd config in rhel6 with lockout_test added to the Post-Auth-Type REJECT block inside post-auth in sites-enabled/default, with the following error in the output of radiusd -X:

```
Module: Checking session {...} for more modules to load
Module: Checking post-proxy {...} for more modules to load
Module: Checking post-auth {...} for more modules to load
/etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default[565]: Failed to load module "lockout_test".
/etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default[565]: Failed to parse "lockout_test" entry.
```

I wonder why it's saying that it's trying to load and parse a module? Is it looking for this function in the modules directory somehow? Do I have a wrong version of freeRadius maybe? Also, I'm wondering whether to put it inside or outside the policy.conf policy {} block. It fails to be loaded into default either way.

Many thanks for any help.

Added a function to policy.conf for radiusd but it wasn't loaded for use in sites-enabled/default.